# How can I detect when a Mousetrap input is NOT being used?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, mousetrap

I'm developing an app that uses text inputs.
I've added Mousetrap to my codebase to utilise shortcuts and it works as expected.

The issue I face:
The regular keyup function also fires when the mouse trap function is called.

I would like to only fire the regular keyup function when a moustrap function isn't being used/called.

I've googled but perhaps am not wording it properly to get the desired help.

Regular `keyup` eventlistener"

```
    textAreaEl.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            console.log('Regular keyup pressed')
    })
```

Mousetrap function:

```
    Mousetrap(textAreaEl).bind(['shift+enter'], function(e) {
        console.log('Shift+Enter pressed')
    })
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks All.
Moe

Comment: Does `stopPropagation` work?

Comment: @user202729 doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: There's still an option to store all the processed event into a variable and mark some events as ignored, but you have to do it yourself. // depends on the library, use `keydown` instead of `keyup` might work.